# removing multiple additions to popup

Tags: openlayers-2, geoext, popup

I am using the GeoExt [example](http://api.geoext.org/1.1/examples/popup-more.html) and this is the [js code](http://api.geoext.org/1.1/examples/popup-more.js) and trying to get rid of the multiple lat and lon that get added into the PopUp on multiple clicks.

Not sure which is the code that I need to comment out? I thought that removing,

```
this.handlerOptions = OpenLayers.Util.extend(
            options && options.handlerOptions || {}, 
            this.defaultHandlerOptions
        );
```

Would do the job but it seems that is not right as I am still getting the multiple popups and commenting out that code made no difference. Not sure what that code was for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to modify code of your Click control:

```js
var control = new OpenLayers.Control.Click({
    trigger: function(evt) {
        var loc = mapPanel.map.getLonLatFromViewPortPx(evt.xy);
        if (popup) popup.close();
        addToPopup(loc);
    }
});
```

Comment: thanks a lot that works beautifully. Another problem is that in the example that i have posted in the question, the popup moves along with the location, in my case it continues to be static. I think it because of the difference in the projection, but do not know how should I change the projection?

Comment: I did add `location: loc.xy` to the `popup = new GeoExt.Popup({})` but still it made no difference.

Comment: Could you create new question and share your code or live demo link?

Comment: here is the question and the link to my app

http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/30767/popup-is-stationary-does-not-move-with-the-location