# Popup is stationary does not move with the location

Tags: openlayers-2, geoext, popup

I am using the GeoExt [example](http://api.geoext.org/1.1/examples/popup-more.html) and used the same code in my application. This is my [code](http://dpaste.de/X5rhT/)

The problem I am facing is that the Popup box in my application on
 `http://128.196.142.94/geo/test/test.html` is stationary. Where ever you may click, the popup simply does not move. Not sure where I am going wrong?

Comment: I had to wrap the link in code since gis stack was not allowing me to post it as a link. You can copy it and paste it in your url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`anchored: false` should be `anchored: true`:

```js
if (!popup) {
    popup = new GeoExt.Popup({
        title: "Popup",
        width: 200,
        maximizable: true,
        collapsible: true,
        map: mapPanel.map,
        anchored: true,
        listeners: {
            close: function() {
                // closing a popup destroys it, but our reference is truthy
                popup = null;
            }
        }
    });
}
```

And remove `location: loc.xy` from popup definition.

`loc.xy` is undefined and if you have a look into GeoExt Popup.js source you can find that in this case `anchored` property automatically sets to `false`.

### UPDATE:

It looks like you are using old version of geoext library. I've adapted your example for working with this version:

```js
var mapPanel, popup;

Ext.onReady(function() {

    function addToPopup(loc) {

        if (!popup) {
            popup = new GeoExt.Popup({
                title: "Popup",
                width: 200,
                maximizable: true,
                collapsible: true,
                map: mapPanel.map,
                /* Fix #1
                   loc - object of OpenLayers.Pixel class
                */
                location: loc,
                anchored: true,
                listeners: {
                    close: function() {
                        popup = null;
                    }
                }
            });
        }

        popup.add({
            xtype: "box",
            autoEl: {
                /* Fix #2
                   Convert pixel coordinates to LonLat
                */
                html: "You clicked on (" + mapPanel.map.getLonLatFromViewPortPx(loc).lon.toFixed(2) + ", " + mapPanel.map.getLonLatFromViewPortPx(loc).lat.toFixed(2) + ")"
            }
        });

        /* Fix #3
           It is not necessary because location was defined within constructor
        */
        //popup.location = loc;

        popup.doLayout();
        popup.show();
    }

    var mapPanel = new GeoExt.MapPanel({
        title: "Map",
        renderTo: "container",
        width: 650, height: 356,
        layers: [
            new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS(
                "Global Imagery",
                "http://maps.opengeo.org/geowebcache/service/wms",
                {layers: "bluemarble"}
            )
        ],
        center: [0, 0],
        zoom: 2
    });

    var control = new OpenLayers.Control.Click({
        trigger: function(evt) {
            /* Fix #4
               Get pixel coordinates from click and send to popup constructor 
            */
            var loc = evt.xy;
            if (popup) popup.close();
            addToPopup(loc);
        }
    });

    mapPanel.map.addControl(control);
    control.activate();

});
```

Comment: Nope it is not working. Made the change, you can check the link, it seems indifferent to the change

Comment: @Sam007 I've updated my answer please check it out.

Comment: Sorry @drnextgis still unchanged. here is the entire code, http://dpaste.de/poV4P/, I might have forgotten something that you might find it in the code. The application is still live, if you want to check.

Comment: @Sam007 please check update of my answer.

Comment: @Sam007 did you try proposed solution?

Comment: Hey @drnextgis sorry for the late response. Yup this final solution works perfectly fine. So why did it make a difference when we did not use `autoEl: {
                html: "You clicked on (" + loc.lon.toFixed(2) + ", " + loc.lat.toFixed(2) + ")"
            }` and instead declared `var loc = panel.map.getLonLatFromViewPortPx(evt.xy);` in the `control` constructor

Answer (score 0):

Try to add these variables to the top of your code. Sometimes if you don't define the variable, OpenLayers has a problem

`var panel, popup;`

I hope it helps you...

Comment: already done. It was giving me an error before, but I added it and now at-least I can see the popup